# How to make fresh fish meat material

Tags: node-editor

I am making a sushi animation lately.
I want to make a piece of fish meat.[image]
Something like the picture.
but I don't know how to make the meat looks translucent.
My piece of sushi looks like plastic.
[image]
I hope anyone who has experience with nodes can give me some advice.
Don't make it too completed.
Thanks

Comment: Hello :). The main issue will be Subsurface Scattering. So the Principled shader is all you need.

Comment: Is this for Eevee or Cycles? I'm not sure why this Q was closed. Obviously, your shader needs an improvement. As mentioned earlier SSS is the key to making the meat look meatier. I would also recommend a Bump map (or Displacement for Cycles). Here's a quick try to give you the idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO6XS.jpg The HDRI is this one: https://polyhaven.com/a/gamrig 
Make sure your model has real-world size (the SSS values depend on it). Play around with the values and different HDRIs.